# Sharing the thumbs.db file

Tags: thumbnails, cifs, thumbs.db

in our situation we got network shares containing a lot of PDF's. People want to look at the thumbnails before opening them. However, the thumbs.db file is regenerated for every user looking at the folder. This seems unnecessary, thus my question, is it possible to 'share' the thumbs.db files? So if user A visits folder X for the first time, thumbs are generated for folder X and if user B visits folder X it loads the thumbnails from the thumbs.db file generated by user A instead of regenerating all thumbnails.

Thanks in advance,
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Normally, they *should* be using the existing thumbnail cache.

However there are a few things that could be tripping things up. One or more clients that are accessing the folders may have different configurations that could be causing the cache to get deleted or modified. Check if any of them:

- Are running Vista or higher which doesn’t use that system for thumbnails anymore
- Have the thumbnail-caching option turned off
- Are running some kind of temp/cache cleanup program
- Using a third-party thumbnail-generation/management shell-extension